# String Parsing Algorithm to validate for numeric and Alphabetic letter

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am working on some project where I need to Parse selected string and validate whether the string has Numeric value and Alphabetic value. Please provide me a solution if you have any idea.

Comment: Could use regular expressions.

Comment: Because you obviously have problems with logic, please, provide a small XML document and the exact expected result from the transformation. You say that you need to test whether a string contains alphabetic characters *and* digits, but in the comments you say that the expression should evaluate to `true()` for `<Var>100-12<Var>` -- which only contains digits and doesn't contain any letter.

Answer (score 0):

**This is `true()` exactly when the string `$s` can be used as a number**:

```
number($s) = number($s)
```

**This is `true()` exactly when a `$s` string is composed only of Latin characters**:

```
string-length(translate($s, $alpha, '')) = 0
```

where $alpha is a string containing all lowercase and uppercase letters.

**This is true when the string `$s` contains at least one letter or number**:

```
not(string-length(translate($s, $alphaNum, '')) = string-length($s))
```

where $alphaNumis a string containing all lowercase and uppercase letters and all digits.

**In XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) one can use regular expressions and character classes**.

**Update**: It seems from the OP's comments that he actually wants to test if a string contains letters *or* digits.

A second new requirement is to store in a variable some part of the string in each case. However, this requirement isn't defined at all and only comes in two contradictory examples given in the OP's comments.

Comment: <xsl:variable name="Value" select="Var"/> This Value variable can contain both letters and numbers for example Value has "Cust12". can you just tell me how to validate whether Variable has both numbers and letters.

Comment: @Hari: Do you want to validate that $Var consists *only* of letters and numbers, or that it *contains* letters and numbers, but may also contain other types of characters?

Comment: Need to check if it contains atleast one letter and number

Comment: @Hari: I updated my answer (see the last expression) to give you exactly this.

Comment: Above logic seems to work if the string has either alpha or numeric characters. My intention is to store it in a variable if the string has at least one alpha and one numeric character otherwise I want to store a substring after '-' in the string. Let us say for example: case1: <Var>100-ax<Var> need to strore 100-ax value into a variable(X). case2: <Var>100-12<Var> need to strore 12 into a variable(X). Why I am stressing here to store into a variable(X) since outputting of X will be done at a later stage.

Comment: @Hari: in your last comment you are contradicting yourself -- the second `Var` doesnt contain "at least one alpha and one numeric character". Please, correct your requirements so that they are meaningful and non-contradictory.

Comment: @Hari: also, in the second case why you want to store only `12` and not `100` or `100-12`? What is the definition/logic of which data to extract in each case?